# I can't find in ../third_party/libevent/event-config.h path to event-config.h for windows OR how to generate event-config.h for windows

Tags: build, webrtc, gn

Good day !

I try to build application with chromium api.

1. I install chromium source code and tools 
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md
2. I can generate visual studio solution  *.sln and compile all projects.
   $ gn gen --ide=vs out\Default
   $ devenv out\Default\all.sln
3. Then I download sample 
   $ git clone https://github.com/dreamer-dead/chromium-sample-app.git sample_app

and try to build project

$ gn gen --args=is_debug=true --root=../ ../out/gn
$ ninja -C ../out/gn sample_app

and I've gotten message - error generate event-config.h for your platform

4. After that I've checked file /third_party/libevent/event-config.h

event-config.h

```
#if defined(__APPLE__)
#include "mac/event-config.h"
#elif defined(ANDROID)
#include "android/event-config.h"
#elif defined(__linux__)
#include "linux/event-config.h"
#elif defined(__FreeBSD__)
#include "freebsd/event-config.h"
#elif defined(__sun)
#include "solaris/event-config.h"
#else
#error generate event-config.h for your platform
#endif
```

I can see that I have not event-config.h  for windows

Question   -  How I can generate event-config.h  for Windows ?

Regards, 
Vladimir

Comment: How is this related to WebRTC? I don't see any references in the code or build config.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake:
`/third_party/libevent/event-config.h` is not related to WebRTC.

The problem was another:

1. I need to set `LIB` and `INCLUDE` in environment (windows sdk).
2. I need to set `PATH` to the correct version of python.